# Count bitmasks, enumerate 0s

Tags: c++, python, c, binary

I had the following question in an interview and I believe I gave a working implementation but I was wondering if there was a better implementation that was quicker, or just a trick I missed.

Given 3 unsigned 30-bit integers, return the number of 30-bit integers that when compared with any of the original numbers have the same position bits set to 1. That is we enumerate all the 0s

Let me give an example, but lets use 4bit for clarity.

Given:

```
A = 1001
B = 0011
C = 0110
```

It should return 8 since there are 8 4bit ints that are in the set. The set being:

```
0011
0110
0111
1001
1011
1101
1110
1111
```

Now how I worked it out was to take each number and enumerate the set of possibilites and then count all the distinct values. How I enumerated the set was to start with the number, add one to it and then OR it with itself until I reached the mask. With the number itself being in the set and the mask (being all set to 1) also in the set. So for example to enumerate the set of 1001:

```
1001 = the start
1011 = (1001 + 1) | 1001
1101 = (1011 + 1) | 1001
1111 = (1101 + 1) | 1001 (this is the last value as we have reached our mask)
```

So do that for each number and then count the uniques.

This is it in python code (but language doesn't really matter as long as you can do bitwise operations, hence why this question is tagged for c/c++ as well):

```
MASK = 0x3FFFFFFF

def count_anded_bitmasks( A, B, C ):
    andSets = set(
      enumerate_all_subsets(A) +
      enumerate_all_subsets(B) +
      enumerate_all_subsets(C)
    )
    return len(andSets)


def enumerate_all_subsets( d ):
    andSet = []
    n = d
    while n != MASK:
        andSet.append(n)
        n = (n + 1) | d
    andSet.append(n)
    return andSet
```

Now this works and gives the correct answer but I'm wondering if I have missed a trick. Since the question was to only ask the count and not enumerate all the values perhaps there is a much quicker way. Either by combining the numbers first, or getting a count without enumeration. I have a feeling there is. Since numbers that contain lots of zeros the enumeration rises exponentially and it can take quite a while.

If you have A B and C, the count of the set of numbers which has bits set to 1 where A or B or C has corresponding bits set to 1.

Some people don't understand the question (didn't help that I didn't ask it correctly first of). Let's use the given A B and C values above:

A:

```
1001
1011
1101
1111
```

B:

```
0011
0111
1011
1111
```

C:

```
0110
0111
1110
1111
```

Now combine those sets and count the distinct entries. That is the answer. Is there a way to do this without enumerating the values?

edit: Sorry for the mistake the question. Fixed now.

Comment: I think this question would be a better fit for codegolf.

Comment: I'm sorry I confused. Firstly you use & in the example and than | in your code. Secondly why isn't 1000 a solution in your example? Could you please clarify, I'm eager to understand :)

Comment: Am I missing something here? When `0001` is ANDed with either `A` or `B` above, it gives a true. Why isn't that considered a possible solution?

Comment: @JohnDibling Not really. The best solution for this might not be the shortest.

Comment: @chrisaycock: Because `0001` gives 0 when ANDed with `C`. It needs to give a nonzero value when ANDed with each one of A,B,C.

Comment: @interjay Does it have to give a nonzero when ANDed with *each*? The phrasing of the question is "when ANDed with *any* of the original numbers is true". There should be some clarification in the question.

Comment: @chrisaycock: The wording is misleading, but the example makes it clear that it needs to be nonzero when ANDed with each one. Plus, the question would be trivial if it wasn't for this.

Comment: Wouldn't `0101` work?  The first `1` matches C, and the second matches A and B.

Comment: @DavidThornley Good catch there too. I think the OP messed-up his example, hence why interjay and I are confused about the *any* vs *each*.

Comment: I think the solution of the example should have `0101` instead of `0110`.

Comment: @chrisaycock:  The `0110` listed in the set could be a mistake for `0101`, since it doesn't AND with A.  At this point, I'm really not certain what the problem is.  My best guess is at variance with both the text description and the examples given.

Comment: @interjay Hmm, that's a good catch too. I think the OP needs to really clarify his question statement.

Comment: Yep I think I messed up the question. I mean that the number compared to the first needs to have the same bits set that the first but the 0's are enumerated. Let me fix the question.

Comment: The question is a lot more confusing after your update. I now have absolutely no idea what you're asking.

Comment: If you have A, the set of numbers which has bits set to 1 where A has corresponding bits set to 1.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
N = 4

def supers(number):
    zeros = sum(1 for bit in xrange(N) if (number >> bit) & 1 == 0)
    return 2**zeros


def solve(a,b,c):
    total = supers(a) + supers(b) + supers(c)
    total -= supers(a | b) # counted twice, remove one
    total -= supers(b | c) # counted twice, remove one
    total -= supers(a | c) # counted twice, remove one
    total += supers(a | b | c) # counted three times, removed three times, add one

    return total


print solve(0b1001,0b0011,0b0110)
```

### Explanation

Let `S(n)` be the set produce by the number `n`.

`supers(n)` returns `|S(n)|` the size of the set for the number n. `supers` is not a great name, but I had trouble coming up with a better one

The trick is to realize that `S(a) ^ S(b) = S(a | b)`. As a result, using supers I can figure out the size of all those sets.

To figure out the rest, draw a venn diagram of the sets.

Comment: A = int('111111111111111111111110011111', 2)
  B = int('111111111111111111111100111111', 2)
  C = int('111111111111111111111101101111', 2)
    
  print solve([A, B, C])

Should print 8 but prints 1073741816

Comment: @dalore, I see the problem being described now is different then the one when I wrote this.

Comment: @dalore, should be correct now, If I understand your problem.

Comment: Yep this works for the test cases I wrote. Accepting this answer and later today I'm going to go through it to make sure I understand it. It looks like you're counting bits (a theory I had but couldn't make it work), but then removing bits you have already counted in others?

Comment: @dalore, added a bit of explanation

Comment: @WinstonEwert for above example A- 1001,B - 0011,C - 0110 , now on considering single variable total is 4+4+4, now on going with ex-or of 2 variable A|B - 4,B|C - 4,C|A - 16 , So total remains 12- 24 = -12, Now going for A|B|C total becomes total = -12 + 4 =-8 ??? Is my understanding correct

Comment: @Anshulgarg, | is bitwise-or not exclusive or.

Comment: @WinstonEwert if it's bitwise OR then also A- 1001,B - 0011,C - 0110 , now on considering single variable total is 4+4+4, now on going with ex-or of 2 variable A|B - 8,B|C - 8,C|A - 16 , So total remains 12- 32 = -20, Now going for A|B|C total becomes total = -20 + 16 =-4 ??? Is my understanding correct

Comment: @Anshulgarg, count the zeros, not the ones.

Answer (score 8):

**EDIT:** updated requirement: *Given 3 unsigned 30-bit integers, return the number of 30-bit integers that when compared with any of the original numbers have the same position bits set to 1. That is we enumerate all the 0s*

OK that's a bit tougher. It's easy to calculate for one number, since in that case the number of possible integers depends only on the number of zero bits, like this:

```
// Count bits not set
const size_t NUMBITS=30;
size_t c;
size_t v = num;
for (c=NUMBITS; v; v >>= 1) 
  c -= v & 1;

return c;
```

Naively you might try extending this to three integers by doing it for each and summing the results, however that would be wrong because the possibilities need to be *unique*, e.g. given

```
A = 1001
B = 0011
C = 0110
```

You would count e.g. 1111 three times rather than once. You should subtract the number of combinations that are shared between any two numbers, but not subtract any combination twice.
**This is simply a C++ translation of Winston Ewert's answer!**

```
size_t zeroperms(size_t v)
{
    // Count number of 0 bits
    size_t c = 1;
    for (c=NUMBITS; v; v >>= 1)
        c -= v & 1;
    // Return number of permutations possible with those bits
    return 1 << c;
}

size_t enumerate(size_t a, size_t b, size_t c)
{
    size_t total = zeroperms(a) + zeroperms(b) + zeroperms(c);
    total -= zeroperms(a | b); // counted twice, remove one
    total -= zeroperms(b | c); // counted twice, remove one
    total -= zeroperms(a | c); // counted twice, remove one
    total += zeroperms(a | b | c); // counted three times, removed three times, add one
    return total;
}
```

Comment: This reports 3 for 1111, 1111, 1111

Comment: Darn messed up for c=0. Fixed.

Comment: Cleaned up the code a bit with a loop and changed it to 30 bits now

Comment: It seems to fail on some of the test cases I've created, unless I've done something wrong, will double check it in the morning: http://pastebin.com/NQdmmdcL

Comment: I think you're right. Should have been more cautious with something I couldn't really prove. It happens to work for some cases, but you can't really remove the duplicate cases with bitwise operations; you have to really subtract them. Winston Ewert's answer is correct.

Comment: OK answer updated - kudos to Winston, so please accept his answer instead of mine. BTW I'm very curious where you got this as an interview question. :-) It's a very nice one.

Comment: Cheers for trying, I was working through the solutions people posted in order of oldest first. Winstons did pass the test

Comment: +1 I only figured out my answer by stealing the correct parts of yours.

Answer (score 1):

In C#
Count the number of zeros. the many zero, the many way you can mask with given number. So, number of zero will make the variation of how many numbers need to consider=> this will be 2^(zero count).

Then accumulate total matches for each three numbers. Here some numbers may came double. So subtract that numbers. Add common numbers that got subtracted for previous number(follow the van diagram of three overlapping circles).

```
public static int count(int d)
    {
        int bits = 0;
        for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++)
        {
            if(((d>>i)&1)==0) bits++;
            //if ((d & 1) == 0) bits++;
            //d >>= 1; //shift right
        }
        return (int)Math.Pow(2, bits);
    }
    public static int BitWiseConfirm(int A, int B, int C)
    {
        // write your code in C# 6.0 with .NET 4.5 (Mono)
        int total = 0;
        total += count(A);
        //Console.WriteLine("total"+total);
        total += count(B);
        //Console.WriteLine("total"+total);
        total += count(C);
        //Console.WriteLine("total"+total);
        //remove duplicates
        total -= count(A | B);
        //Console.WriteLine("total"+total);
        total -= count(B | C);
        //Console.WriteLine("total"+total);
        total -= count(C | A);
        //Console.WriteLine("total"+total);
        total += count(A | B | C);
        //Console.WriteLine("total"+total);
        return total;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Trick 1:

The total answer is the union of each individual 30 bit number. This translates to the bitwise union operator, OR.
This means we can do `D = A | B | C`
With your 4 bit example, we arrive at `D = 1111`
Now we only need to work with 1 number

#### Trick 2:

A little bit of maths tells us that for every `1` we double our possible set of numbers.
This means all you need to do is raise 2 to the power of the number of 1s. Count the 1s with a loop, shifting down each time

```
bits = 0
D = 0b1111 #our number from trick 1
for i in range(4): #here 4 is the number of bits
    if D & 1:
        bits += 1
    D >>= 1 #drop off the smallest number
print 2 ** bits
```

in this case it will print 16

Comment: Aren't you mistakenly including `0` in your count?

Comment: Trick 1 is slightly wrong, `||` in C++ is boolean or, not bitwise or.

Comment: @DanielRoethlisberger Oops, how embarrassing

Comment: Should print 8 for the 4bit example

Comment: @dalore you missed a bunch (8) of numbers from valid possibilites in your example, for example 0001 is true when ANDed by both A and B

Comment: @dalore, I think you updated your question, which changed what the answer should be. My answer is in response to the original question

Comment: ok sorry I got the question wrong, but the examples were correct